# How to get value of each array element in JSON?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://testsite.com/testurl.php",
    data: form,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log( 'success', data );
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log( 'error', arguments );
    }
});
```

In result we get this JSON:

```
{
   "answer" : {
      "domains" : [
         {
            "dname" : "ab.ru",
            "error_code" : "DOMAIN_EXISTS",
            "error_params" : {
               "dname" : "ab.ru",
               "servtype" : "domain"
            },
            "error_text" : "Domain exists",
            "result" : "error"
         },
         {
            "dname" : "ab.com",
            "error_code" : "DOMAIN_EXISTS",
            "error_params" : {
               "dname" : "ab.com",
               "servtype" : "domain"
            },
            "error_text" : "Domain exists",
            "result" : "error"
         },
         ...,
         {
            "dname" : "zz.com",
            "error_code" : "DOMAIN_EXISTS",
            "error_params" : {
               "dname" : "ab.com",
               "servtype" : "domain"
            },
            "error_text" : "Domain exists",
            "result" : "error"
         },
        "error_text" : "Domain already exists, use whois service",
        "result" : "error"
     }
      ]
   },
   "charset" : "utf-8",
   "result" : "success"
}
```

Tell me please how get each `answer.domains[] ->dname` and `answer.domains[] ->error_code`?

For example for first array it will be:

```
dname = ab.ru;
error_code = DOMAIN_EXISTS;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop and and do your work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.answer.domains.length; i++) {
    var domain = data.answer.domains[i];

    //domain is the specific domain being iterated
    //domain.dname; -> zz.com
}
```